# Compliant code marked bug in Sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

[Rule 3923](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/type/Bug/RSPEC-3923) mentions the exception that it does not apply when the `if` statement does not have an `else` or a `switch` construct does not have a default. But [here](https://sonarqube.ow2.org/project/issues?id=fr.inria.gforge.spoon%3Aspoon-core&resolved=false&rules=squid%3AS3923&types=BUG), they are marked as bug.

Same is the case with [SAT4J](https://sonarqube.ow2.org/project/issues?id=org.ow2.sat4j%3Aorg.ow2.sat4j.pom&resolved=false&rules=squid%3AS2201&types=BUG) for this [bug](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/type/Bug/RSPEC-2201) .

Can anyone from the Sonarqube community address this and open an issue in sonarqube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upgrade to a newer version of SonarJava. The [description of the rule on your server](https://sonarqube.ow2.org/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS3923) does not mention the exception which you expect.

Comment: Oh thank you. I was looking at the description somewhere else.